# Identify all editors in SP

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, 2016, sharepoint-permissions

For our corporate SP 2016 web sites, basically everybody in our department had editing permissions until now.
I am trying to find out who actually edited any content on these sites, and make them editors. Everybody else should become a visitor.
SP views provide "Created by" and "Modified by".
But what about documents modified by person A and modified again by person B? There is no record of person A. How can I find out who they are?
I've spent hours looking for info on this, no luck so far ... hope you can help.
Thanks in advance,
-NM-
P.S. no access to SP Designer.

Answer (score 0):

If your farm enabled auditing before, you can check the audit log for all editing events and find out the users who have modified anything. You can check more information about audit log here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/configure-audit-data-for-a-site-collection-a9920c97-38c0-44f2-8bcb-4cf1e2ae22d2#ID0EAADAAA=SharePoint_Server_2019,_2016,_2013

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-audit-log-reports-b37c5869-1b47-4a82-a30d-ea20070fe527

Comment: Thank you - I guess I'll have to approach our SP admins or access to the audit log.